# SAS store macro reference in macro variable

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I want to store a list of macro references in another macro variable and then change the content of one of the referenced variables.

As example:

```
%LET String=FirstString; 
%LET KeepMacroNotString=&String; 
%PUT &String = &KeepMacroNotString ?;  


%LET String=String changed; 
%PUT &String = &KeepMacroNotString?;
```

In the end I would like that %PUT &KeepMacroNotString resolves to "String changed". However it sticks to the first assignment.

Any ideas? 
Thx, Lubenja

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Much easier to do with a data step.

```
data _null_;
  call symputx('KeepMacroNotString','&String');
run;
```

Comment: Yes, much easier, as you can use the macro &KeepMacroNotString 
1) without using the unquote function and 2) without the need to reasign it. Thx! Lubenja

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution: 
A combination of the %NRSTR function and the %UNQUOTE function do the trick:

```
%LET String=FirstString; 
%LET KeepMacroNotString=%NRSTR(&String); 
%PUT &String = &KeepMacroNotString ?;  

%LET String=String changed; 
%PUT &String = %UNQUOTE(&KeepMacroNotString)?;
```

Explanation: First you have to mask the "&" to prevent the macro from being resolved (%NRSTR()). 
But when you want to use the marco, then you have to unquote it again (%UNQUOTE()).

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use this approach, but if you don't mind warning messages in the log (I do), you could in theory just change the order of your statements:

```
WARNING: Apparent symbolic reference STRING not resolved.
 57         
 58             %LET KeepMacroNotString=&String;
 59         
 60             %LET String=FirstString;
 61             %PUT &String = &KeepMacroNotString ?;
 FirstString = FirstString ?
 62         
 63             %LET String=String changed;
 64             %PUT &String = &KeepMacroNotString?;
 String changed = String changed?
```

This is basically an ugly way of accomplishing the same sort of indirection that Tom did more gracefully.  Key point being that that the macro variable KeepMacroNotString is given a value of &String, not the resolved value.

In a macro setting, this can also be accomplished by assigning default value as a macro variable reference, e.g.:

```
 59         %macro indirect(String=
 60                 ,KeepMacroNotString=&string
 61                 );
 62           %put _local_;
 63           %put &string = &keepmacronotstring;
 64         %mend indirect;
 65         %indirect(string=Hi)
 INDIRECT KEEPMACRONOTSTRING &string
 INDIRECT STRING Hi
 Hi = Hi
```